# DFP small business - using 1 ad unit tag to create a several inventory by modifying the tag

Tags: google-dfp

I am new with DFP, but I want to know if it's possible to customize the ad tag, otherwise I will need to create a bunch of ad unit in the DFP and use custom targeting to allocate the ad.

Example of the tag:

http://prntscr.com/5ee0b1

Comment: there's no screenshot available in the link.

Comment: Fixed the link to the screenshot but I'm unsure what @Squart is trying to accomplish? Targeting is done in the 'defineSlot' part of your script. The only thing that happens in the 'display()' part is showing the slot that you defined in the first part of you code. BTW you have quite a few JavaScript errors in your screenshot. For instance gptadslots[Top] should be gptadslots['Top'] and your quotes are pretty messed up (you're using smart quotes). Check your javascript console.